# Magento 2 : Payment Gateway - Terms of Service

Tags: magento-2.1, payment

The default/core payment gateways in Magento 2 check if user has accepted `terms of service` before allowing checkout.

There is a sample payment gateway here for Magento 2:
https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway

It doesn't implement `terms of service` validation and even if they are activated, they are not displayed for this payment gateway => the user can checkout without agreeing with the TOS.

There is some doc about field validators but nothing about the TOS validation in particular. The TOS checkbox is a bit different from other fields as it doesn't seem to be created in the module template files.

How is the TOS validation supposed to be implemented in a custom payment gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this in the Magento 2 doc here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html